# Uploaded file is null. How to check why?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi

I have this action in the controller.

```cs
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm]IFormFile upfile)
    {...
    }
```

When i test this action i get `upfile` is null. As i understand framework makes model binding and result of this operation is null, no errors. So i can not check why it returns null. Is there any way to check why binding is returning null and how to fix that ?

Comment: Try taking out `[FromForm]` or changing to a `List<IFormFile>`. There are some other things you can try on [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1#customize-model-binding-behavior-with-attributes)

Comment: Make sure the upload field in html has the same name as the variable. Also, if you are using .net core 2.1, try adding Name = "upfile" to your FromForm attribute like this: [FromForm(Name = "upfile")]IFormFile upfile.

Comment: Please use Chrome Developer Tools to view the payload being submitted to the server. Please update your question to show it to us.

Comment: Upload field should match parameter name is the right answer. I used Postman and didn't specify key when was sending request. So key should be "upfile" in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. You need key that equals parameter name. In my case key = upfile. If you use Postman then check if you wrote key before sending request.

[image]

Still there is no answer how to check an error. In this case error like "File name is not found you should specify key value" or something from binding would be more then helpful.

Comment: You can also add `[ApiController]` attribute and it will work even without name.